# How to remove text which was added via chart.renderer in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts, label

I have added labels to my graph, instead of a legend ([see fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/6g5ttbfr/4/)). Once the graph has been drawn, with those series labels attached to it via chart.renderer.text, the user can click on a button in order to add an additional series, which, in turn, suppresses other lines (successfully). However, how can I get rid now of these labels - which stand there in the void now.

Example: this is the full set of lines and labels:
[image]

And this is when a button has been clicked in order to show an additional line, which suppresses at the same time four other lines:
[image]

I add the labels like this:

```
chart.renderer.text('Volcanic', 1170, 360)
  .css({
    fontSize: '13px',
    color: '#7d7d7d'
  })
.add();
```

Now, these labels are still there - but should go away. Any way I can achieve this? The possibility to add an ID, and then call a chart.renderer.byID(xy).remove() or something similar?

Comment: so you want to remove a serie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at HC documentation, the only rendered element that seems to be removable is the rendered.path.  However, looking at your code, you can use jquery to remove elements that got rendered.  The text rendered in either text or a tspan within a text.

jquery, remove it like this.  The code below will  remove all (texts and series) when natural is clicked

```
var natural = ['Volcanic','Solar','Ozone','Orbital Changes']
 $(natural).each(function(i,d){
                chart.get(d).remove();
                $('tspan:contains("'+d+'")').closest('text').remove()
                $('text:contains("'+d+'")').remove()
            })
```

furthermore, i see that you hard coded the x,y location of your text rendered which is problematic when viewing in jsfiddle or when the screen is too small or too big.  you can use plotX and plotY to determine where the line ends and plot it there.  example:

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
var point = chart.get('Land Use').points 'get all the plotted points
  point[point.length-1].plotX ' length -1 is the last point, this is x, plotY will get you y.
```

Lastly, i think you're after the hide function since you will want to bring these (removed) series back when the other button is clicked.  Hence, if you removed, you will have to re-render the series.

Comment: Wow, cool. The "remove code and text" is working great! Thanks so much. And yes, it should be a "hide()" and not a "remove()". Very good. A dynamic positioning of the labels would be perfect. However, I don't succeed in getting this running. I think it's a question of rendering the graph first, and placing the labels then? But that would mean that I can't display the lines with the corresponding label one after another? Or should the graph be rendered then after each line? Thanks so much for your help! [updated fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/6g5ttbfr/5/).

Comment: you can do it 1 of 2 ways, just try and get the plotx and y in the exact same area you're doing it right now.  if that doesn't work.  create a text render function and renter it after the chart is rendered.  I think you will need it otherwise your text will be out of place most of the time.

Answer (score 11):

You can remove rendered objects by calling `.destroy()` on them. 
All you need to do is assigning the objects to a variable.

```
var objLabel; // assign the var so it is reachable in your scope

objLabel = $('#container').highcharts().renderer.text('Volcanic', 100, 30)
  .css({
    fontSize: '13px',
    color: '#7d7d7d'
  })
.add();
```

Here is a fiddle to prove the point: http://jsfiddle.net/jfpq6zcg/

Comment: This works well for all custom rendered objects. I use the chart object itself to store these references

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for doing it the highcharts way.